# Relative connection string to AzMan XML store when using security application block

Tags: enterprise-library, relative-path, azman

Is it possible to specify a relative connection string for an AzMan XML store?

My current connection string is `connectionString="msxml://c:/azman.xml"` but I really need to make that relative so other developers and automated builds can get the latest authorization store.

MS documentation seems to suggest that `connectionString="msxml://azman.xml"` should work but that throws a `The request is not supported` error.

EDIT: I realised that the fact I'm using AzMan through the Enterprise Library Security Application Block was important to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to enter the token {currentPath} into the connection string used by the security application block.

This gave me the behavior I was after, allowing the AzMan.xml file to be accessed from with the application folder.

The connection string I am using is:

```
<authorizationProviders>
  <add storeLocation="msxml://{currentPath}/azman.xml"
    application="My_Application" scope="" auditIdentifierPrefix="AzMan Authorization Provider"
    type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.AzMan.AzManAuthorizationProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.AzMan, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    name="AzMan Provider" />
</authorizationProviders>
```

Comment: When I use this technique, in a web app, the currentPath is being evaluated as "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv" rather than the app directory. How do I get it to map to the application dir?

Comment: Using {baseDirectory} worked for me, allowing the file to be found under the web application directory.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the ~ will make it relative to the application

```
<add name="AuthorizationServices" connectionString="msxml://~/App_Data/AzMan.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use {currentPath}, be sure your current directory is properly set before you make the "AuthorizationFactory.GetAuthorizationProvider" call.  I am also using the Enterprise Library Security Application Block.
Ex.
   My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath